# Another little guinea pig

Tags: visual, cipher

I'm a little guinea pig and I love cipher puzzle soo much!

[image]

In Guinea Pig's language my name is:

```
00000220 0
00000260 3
00010020 F
00010140 E
00019010 E
```

Please, someone helps me to pronounce it in human language?

Hints:

> My photo is important :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your name is:

> Conan

Because

> at offsets 220h, 263h, 1002Fh, 1014Eh, 1901Eh in the photo file those 5 letters are read.

Comment: Yes, my name is Conan!

Comment: Could you explain some more detail for steganography n00bs like me? I see 220 1002 (0) 3 ..., but why do you truncate some right hand zeros? What are the "h"s? What method did you use for looking at the photo's data to "read" the letters?

Comment: @JonathanAllan "h" is used when the number has to be read as hexadecimal number. If you open the file (image) with hex editor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) these numbers represent positions in the file from which to read individual characters. The numbers are direct sum of hexadecimals numbers in the left column with hex numbers in the right column, for ex. 00010140 + E = 1014E

Comment: Thanks. I did not know of such notation; I would have known what it meant if I saw $(PQRS)_{16}$ or 0xPQRS though.

Comment: @JonathanAllan There are several notations for hex numbers: 0x012AB, $012AB, 012ABh 012AB(16)... and many others, but the first tree are most common in IT world

Comment: Interesting, I only ever saw 0x in 10+ years, and in Engineering only saw 0x and $()_{16}$. Must have just dodged me somehow.

Comment: @Jonathan I've noticed the `00h` notation is more common when dealing with hardware (I first encountered it when writing assembler for a microcontroller)